# How to do style in GooglePlacesAutocomplete like Text Input in React Native

Tags: json, react-native, autocomplete

I am working on  react-places-autocomplete in react native i want a style like Textinput......

here is image  I want result like this[First is GooglePlacesAutocomplete and second is TextInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVJKh.jpg)

```
const App = () => {


  return (
    <View>
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        placeholder='Search'
        fetchDetails={true}
        onPress={(data, details) => {
          // console.log('data: ', data);
          console.log('details: ', details);
          alert(details.formatted_address)
        }}
        query={{
          key: '',
          language: 'en',
        }}
      />

      <Text>{'\n'}</Text>
      <Text>{'\n'}</Text>
     <Text>{'\n'}</Text>

        <TextInput
          placeholder='Search here....'
          style={{width:350,height:40,borderBottomColor:'black',borderBottomWidth:1,paddingLeft:10,fontSize:20}}
        />

    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
`



How I Can get output like image??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use format like this and customize the Input.

```
 <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
   placeholder="Search location....."
   textInputProps={{
    placeholderTextColor: '#2ff',
   }}
   minLength={1}
   fetchDetails={true}
   styles={{
    listView: {},
    textInputContainer: {},
    textInput: {},
   }}
   debounce={300}
  />
```

You can add style in `textInput` as per your need.

Comment: yes it's working                                                                                                                  
but placeholder text color is not working what I can do???

Comment: You can use textInputProps to set placeholdercolor in it. I have updated the code please check

Comment: it's done thank you!1